# Если b простое число почему-то работает else{} то Почему код не правильно работает?

Tags: c#

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
namespace _2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            double b = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            string v = "";
            for (int i = 1; i <= b; i++)
            {
                if (b % i == 0 && b == i)
                {
                    v = "prime number";
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    v = "Not prime number";
                }
                Console.WriteLine(v);
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («почему этот код не работает?») должны включать желаемое поведение, конкретную проблему или ошибку и минимальный код для её воспроизведения прямо в вопросе. Вопросы без явного описания проблемы бесполезны для остальных посетителей.

Comment: Код работает именно так как он написан. Неверное определение простоты числа

Comment: а  как исправить,?

Comment: А как вы хотите чтобы он работал?

Answer (score 1):

Как-то так:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(String[] args)
    {
        foreach(var x in
            GetPrimeNumbers(1, Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine())))
            Console.Write($"{x}, ");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    // Метод генерирует последовательность простых чисел от low до high
    static IEnumerable<Int32> GetPrimeNumbers(Int32 low, Int32 high)
    {
        if(low == 1) low++;
        for (var i = low; i <= high; i++)
        {
            // Функция проверяет число, является ли оно простым (Решето Эратосфена)
            Boolean IsPrimeNumber(Int32 n)
            {
                for (var i = 2; i <= n / 2; i++)
                {
                    if (n % i == 0) return false;
                }
                return true;
            }
            if (IsPrimeNumber(i)) yield return i;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Перед вторым циклом лучше сделать проверку деления на 2, а в цикле уже начинать с i=3, и не i++, а i+=2. Так будет меньше итераций